# Service context is null

Tags: android

I am consuming some proprietary code (SDK) that calls `ContextWrapper.getPackageName()` internally. When running calling the code from a service I am getting a `NullPointerException`. on the context object.

As some background information, the service runs as a separate process but I have direct access to the service class. If I pass in the context of the main UI app (Activity) then all works fine. The problem arises if I try and use the Service instance.

I have a feeling that the context might not yet have been fully initialised by the time it is being called upon. At what point should I call it?

Why is the context null?

Here is some code - I have tried instantiating the SDK from within the `Service.onBind()` and `ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected()` functions.

```
@Override
 public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {

      try {
           sdk = new SDK(SDKService.this);

           sdk.setCallbacks(sdkWrapperCallbacks);

           connectionCallbacks.onConnected(messengerInbound);
      }
      catch (final Exception e) {

           e.printStackTrace();

           connectionCallbacks.onConnectionError(e.getMessage());
      }
 }

 @Override
 public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {

      connectionCallbacks.onDisconnected();
 }


@Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        SDK = new SDK(SDKService.this);

        SDK.setCallbacks(sdkWrapperCallbacks);

        connectionCallbacks.onConnected(messengerInbound);   

        return messengerInbound.getBinder();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get your context in service with the use of `getApplicationContext()` while that service is being run in separate process then its is by design. Your service has no access to application context, but it has access to local service context which can be accesses by using `this`.

Comment: When I use `this` the `mBaseContext` in `ContextWrapper` is `null` and therefore throws a NPE. Why is this?